# Rename all the folders by removing specific part of first digits or characters from it is name

Tags: directory, rename

I have a long list of folders as follows:

```
001_bat_3513
002_mon_3213
003_bat_3515
scd_btt_3540
s52_bat_4513
xx2_bpt_8523
056_bot_3513
058_bat_1513
.
.
```

From this list: 
How can I rename all the folders by removing the first three numbers or characters from its name? So the list becomes as follows:

```
bat_3513
mon_3213
bat_3515
btt_3540
bat_4513
bpt_8523
bot_3513
bat_1513
.
.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your shell supports parameter expansion:

```
for f in *_*_*; do mv -i "$f" "${f#*_}"; done
```

- The parameter expansion pattern, `${f#*_}`, removes the substring upto first `_` from left

Or using `rename` (`prename`):

```
rename 's/^[^_]*_(.*)/$1/' *_*_*
```

- `^[^_]*_` matches the substring upto first `_` from start and `(.*)` matches the rest, it is also put into the first matched group which is used in replacement

Comment: Does "f#" means removing the first digits. Thank you verym uch

Comment: @goro Check my edits..

Comment: If I want to remove the last four digits. is it correct to use for f in *_*_*; do mv "$f" "${*_*_f#}"; done

Comment: USe `mv -i` just in case there's a filename conflict; also hope there's no directory of the target name.

Comment: @StephenHarris good point..edited..

Comment: @goro That would be `for f in *_*_*; do mv -i "$f" "${f%_*}"; done`